# Simple mathematical console application

Tags: c++, optimization, beginner, mathematics, console

I am new to C++ and with my basic knowledge of the language, I have attempted to create a simple console application filled with lots of useful functions involving math related stuff.

The following is the only version of it that I have created thus far: (also available [here](https://gist.github.com/NickKartha/6387434)).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

string cmd;
bool moduleRun = true;

//Decorations
void finline(string appName){cout<<"Quiting "<<appName<<" ... ";}
void h(string title, char type){
    int l = title.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*(l + 1); i++){
        cout<< type;
        if( i == l /*|| i == 2 * l + 1*/ ){ cout << "\n"; }
        if( i == l ){ cout << " " << title << "\n"; }
    }
}
//End of Decorations

//Modules

//Basic 2 number Calculator Module
void calculator(){
    char op;
    double n1,n2;
    h("Calculator", '-');
    cout<< "\n Perform an operation on 2 numbers using basic operators.\n  eg: 2+2, 4*3, 5%4, 6/7 etc \t\t[ Type '0x 0' to exit ]\n\n";
    while(moduleRun){
        cin>> n1 >> op >> n2;
        switch(op){
            //case '%' :
            case '+' : cout<<n1 + n2 ; break;
            case '-' : cout<< n1 - n2 ; break;
            case 'x' : if(n1 == 0 && n2 == 0){ finline("c4lql80r"); moduleRun = false;}
            case '*' : cout<< n1 * n2 ; break;
            case '/' : cout<< n1/n2; break;
            case '^' : cout<< pow(n1,n2); break;
            case '<' : (n1<n2)?cout<<"True":cout<<"False"; break;
            case '>' : (n1>n2)?cout<<"True":cout<<"False"; break;
            case '=' : (n1==n2)?cout<<"True":cout<<"False"; break;
            default :
                if(op == '%'){int N1 = floor(n1); int N2 = floor(n2); cout << N1 % N2;}
                else{cout<< "That operation is not available";}
        }
        if(moduleRun)cout<< "\n\n";
    }
}

//Functions Module
bool isPrime(long int n) {
    if (n == 2) { return true; }
    if (n < 2 || !(n&1)) { return false; }
    long double l = floor(pow(n, 0.5));
    for (long int i = 3; i <= l; i += 2) { if (n % i == 0) {return false;}}
    return true;
}

long double sum(int n){
    int arr[n];
    long double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<i + 1;
        (i==0)?cout<<"st":(i==1)?cout<<"nd":(i==2)?cout<<"rd":cout<<"th";
        cout<<">> ";
        cin>>arr[i];
        total+=arr[i];
    }
    return total;
}

long double mean(int n){ return ( sum(n) / n ); }

long double prod(int n){
    int arr[n];
    long double product = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<i + 1;
        (i==0)?cout<<"st":(i==1)?cout<<"nd":(i==2)?cout<<"rd":cout<<"th";
        cout<<">> ";
        cin>>arr[i];
        product*=arr[i];
    }
    cout<<"Product = ";
    return product;
}

long double factorial(int n){ //max is 16!
    int fact = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){fact*=i;}
    return fact;
}
//Sequence&Series functions

long int fibterm(int n) { long int term = (n < 2) ? n : fibterm(n - 1) + fibterm(n - 2); return term;};
void fib(int n){ for(int i = 0; i<=n ; i++) cout<<fibterm(i)<<" "; }
long int fibsum(int n){
    long int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++){total+=fibterm(i);} //Please find a formula to reduce processing
    return total;
}

long int lucasterm(int n){ long int term = (n == 1)? 2: (n == 2)? 1: lucasterm(n - 1) + lucasterm(n - 2); return term; }
void lucas( int n ){ for( int i = 0; i<=n ; i++ ) cout << lucasterm(i)<<" "; }
long int lucassum(double n){
    long int total = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){total+=lucasterm(i);} //Please find a formula to reduce processing
    return total;
}

long int oddterm(int n){ return 2*(n-1);}
void odd(int n){ for( int i = 0; i<=n ; i++ ) cout << oddterm(i)<<" "; }
long int oddsum(int n){return pow(n,2);}

void prime(int n){ //prints n primes
    int p = 0, i = 1;
    while(p<=n){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            cout<<i<<" ";
            p++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

//End of Sequence and series functions
void functions(){
    string &func = cmd;
    double param;
    h("Scientific Functions", '-');
    cout<<"\n eg: log 20, sin 60, cosh 40, atan 80, etc \n [ Type 'func 101' for a list of all available functions & '0x 0' to exit]\n";
    while(moduleRun){
        cin>> func >> param;
        //Trigo
        if(func == "sin") cout<< sin(param);
        else if(func == "cos") cout<< cos(param);
        else if(func == "tan") cout<< tan(param);
        else if(func == "sinh") cout<< sinh(param);
        else if(func == "cosh") cout<< cosh(param);
        else if(func == "tanh") cout<< tanh(param);
        else if(func == "asin") cout<< asin(param);
        else if(func == "acos") cout<< acos(param);
        else if(func == "atan") cout<< atan(param);
        //Scientific
        else if(func == "exp") cout<< exp(param);
        else if(func == "log") cout<< log10(param);
        else if(func == "ln") cout<< log(param);
        //Sequence&Series fuAnctions
        else if(func == "fib") fib(param);
        else if(func == "fib.term") cout<< fibterm(param);
        else if(func == "fib.sum") cout << fibsum(param);
        else if(func == "lucas") lucas(param);
        else if(func == "lucas.term") cout<< lucasterm(param);
        else if(func == "lucas.sum") cout << lucassum(param);
        else if(func == "odd")odd(param);
        else if(func == "odd.term")oddterm(param);
        else if(func == "odd.sum")oddsum(param);
        //Other
        else if(func == "sum"){cout<<"Total = "<<sum(param);}
        else if(func == "prod" || func == "product" || func == "multiply"){cout<< prod(param);}
        else if(func == "mean" || func == "average" || func == "avg"){cout << "Arithmetic Mean = "<<mean(param);}
        else if(func == "fact" || func == "factorial"){cout<< factorial(param);}
        else if(func == "isprime") (isPrime(param))? cout<<"Yes, it is prime":cout<<"No, it's not prime";
    //ModuleSupport
        else if(func == "function" || func == "functions" || func == "func"){
            cout<< "\nTrig Functions:\n sin,cos,tan,sinh,cosh,tanh,asin,acos,atan\n\nScientific Functions:\nexp,log,ln\n";
        }
        else if(func == "exit" || func == "0x" || func == "0 x"){
            moduleRun = false;
            finline("Sc13nt1fic funct10n5");
        }
        else {
            cout<< "function not available.\n";
        }
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }
}
//End of Functions Module

void converter(){
    double n, pi = 3.141592653589793;
    string u1, u2;
    h("Converter",'-');
    cout<<"\n eg: 2m to km, 92cm to km, 34 deg to rad, etc \nWARNING: HIGHLY EXPERIMENTAL\n\n";
    while(moduleRun){
        cin>>n>>u1;
        cout<<"to ";
        cin>>u2;
        if(u1 == u2){cout<< n;}
        //Length
        else if(u1 == "mm" || u1 == "millimetre"){
            if(u2 == "cm" || u1 == "centimetre" ) cout << ( n * pow(10,-1) );
            else if( u2 == "dm" || u1 == "decimetre" ) cout << ( n * pow(10,-2) );
            else if( u2 == "m" || u1 == "metre") cout << ( n * pow(10,-3) );
            else if( u2 == "dam"  || u1 == "decametre") cout << ( n * pow(10,-4) );
            else if(u2 == "hm" || u1 == "hectometre") cout << (n * pow(10,-5));
            else if(u2 == "km" || u1 == "kilometre") cout << (n * pow(10,-6));
        }
        else if( u1 == "cm" ){
            if(u2 == "mm" || u1 == "millimetre") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "dm" || u1 == "decimetre" ) cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if(u2 == "m") cout<< (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if(u2 == "dam") cout<< (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if(u2 == "hm") cout<< (n * pow(10,-4));
        else if(u2 == "km") cout<< (n * pow(10,-5));
        }
        else if( u1 == "dm" ){
            if(u2 == "mm") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "cm") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "m") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if(u2 == "dam") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if(u2 == "hm") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if(u2 == "km") cout << (n * pow(10,-4));
        }
        else if( u1 == "dm" ){
            if(u2 == "mm") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "cm") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "m") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if(u2 == "dam") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if(u2 == "hm") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if(u2 == "km") cout << (n * pow(10,-4));
        }
        else if( u1 == "m"){
            if(u2 == "mm") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if(u2 == "cm") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "dm") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "dam") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if(u2 == "hm") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if(u2 == "km") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
        }
        else if( u1 == "dam"){
            if(u2 == "mm") cout << (n * pow(10,4));
            else if(u2 == "cm") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if(u2 == "dm") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "m") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "hm") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if(u2 == "km") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
        }
        else if( u1 == "hm"){
            if(u2 == "mm") cout << (n * pow(10,5));
            else if(u2 == "cm") cout << (n * pow(10,4));
            else if(u2 == "dm") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if(u2 == "m") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "da") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "km") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
        }
        else if( u1 == "km"){
            if(u2 == "mm") cout << (n * pow(10,6));
            else if(u2 == "cm") cout << (n * pow(10,5));
            else if(u2 == "dm") cout << (n * pow(10,4));
            else if(u2 == "m") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if(u2 == "da") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "hm") cout << (n * 10);
        }
        //Mass
        else if( u1 == "mg"){
            if(u2 == "cg") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if( u2 == "dg") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if( u2 == "g") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if( u2 == "dag") cout << (n * pow(10,-4));
            else if( u2 == "hg") cout << (n * pow(10,-5));
            else if( u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-6));
        }
        else if( u1 == "cg" ){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * 10);
            else if( u2 == "dg") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if( u2 == "g") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if( u2 == "dag") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if( u2 == "hg") cout << (n * pow(10,-4));
            else if( u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-5));
        }
        else if( u1 == "dg" ){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if( u2 == "cg") cout << (n * 10);
            else if( u2 == "g") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if( u2 == "dag") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if( u2 == "hg") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if( u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-4));
        }
        else if( u1 == "dg" ){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if( u2 == "cg") cout << (n * 10);
            else if( u2 == "g") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if( u2 == "dag") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if( u2 == "hg") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
            else if( u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-4));
        }
        else if( u1 == "g"){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if( u2 == "cg") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if( u2 == "dg") cout << (n * 10);
            else if( u2 == "dag") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if( u2 == "hg") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
            else if( u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-3));
        }
        else if( u1 == "dag"){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * pow(10,4));
            else if( u2 == "cg") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if( u2 == "dg") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if( u2 == "g") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "hg") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
            else if(u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-2));
        }
        else if( u1 == "hg"){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * pow(10,5));
            else if(u2 == "cg") cout << (n * pow(10,4));
            else if(u2 == "dg") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if(u2 == "g") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "dg") cout << (n * 10);
            else if(u2 == "kg") cout << (n * pow(10,-1));
        }
        else if( u1 == "kg" ){
            if(u2 == "mg") cout << (n * pow(10,6));
            else if(u2 == "cg") cout << (n * pow(10,5));
            else if(u2 == "dg") cout << (n * pow(10,4));
            else if(u2 == "g") cout << (n * pow(10,3));
            else if(u2 == "dg") cout << (n * pow(10,2));
            else if(u2 == "hg") cout << (n * 10);
        }
        //Angular measure
        else if ( u1 == "deg" || u1 == "degrees"){ if( u2 == "radians" || u2 == "rad") cout << (n*pi/180);}
        else if ( u1 == "radians" || u1 == "rad"){ if(u2 == "deg" || u2 == "degrees") cout << (n*180/pi);}
        else{
            cout <<"\n conversion not available from "<< u1 << " to";
            moduleRun = false;
        }
        cout<<" "<<u2<<"\n\n";
        if(!moduleRun){finline("c0nv3rt3r");}
    }
}
void quad(){
    int a,b,c;
    h("Quadratic Solver", '-');
    cout<<"\n Solves the value for x in a quadratic of the form ax^2 + bx + c = 0\n";
    cout<<"\nEnter the coefficient of x^2 >> ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"\nEnter the coefficient of x >> ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"\nEnter the numerical value >> ";
    cin>>c;
    double d = pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);
    if( d < 0 ){ cout<<"\nThere are no real roots possible"; }
    else if(d == 0){ cout<<"\nThe root is "<<(-1*b)/(2*a);}
    else{ cout<<"\nThe roots are "<< (sqrt(d) - b) / (2 * a) << " & " << (-1*( sqrt(d) + b )) / ( 2 * a ); }
}

//Games Module
bool play = true;
bool gameRun = true;
void solve(){
    h("Solve",'*');
    int sel, qn = 0, score = 0;
    double ans;
    char op[4];
    op[0] = '+'; op[1] = '-'; op[2] = '*'; op[3] = '/';
    while(gameRun){
        ++qn;
        double a = floor(rand()%100), b = floor(rand()%100);
        sel = rand()%4; //#Rand(0 to 3)
        if(sel == 3){a = b*(rand()%10);}
        cout<<"\n\n"<<a << op[sel] << b << '\n';
        cin>>ans;
        switch(sel){
            case 0:
                if( ans == (a + b) ){ cout<< "You are correct"; score++;}
                else{cout<<"Wrong the answer was "<< a + b;}
                break;
            case 1:
                if( ans == (a - b) ){ cout<< "Absolutely Right"; score++;}
                else{cout<<"Wrong the answer was "<< a - b;}
                break;
            case 2:
                if( ans == (a * b) ){ cout<< "You are correct"; score++;}
                else{cout<<"Wrong the answer was "<< a * b;}
                break;
            case 3:
                if( ans == (a / b) ){ cout<< "Absolutely Right"; score++;}
                else{cout<<"Wrong the answer was "<< a / b;}
                break;
            default: cout<<"\n!!An unexpected error has occured!!";
        }
        if(qn>100){
            if(score>=50){cout<<"\nGood Job, You've won";}
            else{cout<<"\nYou can do better";}
            cout<< "\nYour score is "<< score;
            cout<< "\n\n Do you wish to play again(y/n)? ";
            cin>> cmd;
            if(cmd == "n" || cmd == "no"){cout<<"\nThank you for playing."; gameRun = false;}
            else{score = 0; qn = 0;}
        }
    }
}

void guessthenumber(){
    h("Guess the number",'*');
    cout<<"\nTry to guess the super random number that the computer has chosen\n\n";
    while(gameRun){
        bool play = true;
        int number = rand(), tries = 0, guess;
        while(play){ // loop to allow repeted guessing
            cin>>guess;
            tries++;
            if(guess>number){cout<<"The number is smaller\n";}
            else if(guess<number){cout<<"The number is larger\n";}
            else if(guess==number){
                play = false;
                cout << "\nYou win, that was the number\n It only took you "<<tries<<" tries\n";
                cout << "\nDo you wish to play again?(y/n) ";
                cin>>cmd;
                if( cmd =="n" || cmd =="no"){gameRun = false;} //ends game loop
                else{ cout<<"\nGuess the new number\n"; }
            }
        }
    }
}

void games(){
    h("The Games Module", '-');
    cout<<"\nThe available games are :\n Solve - Solve a 101 little arithmatic problems\n 'GuessTheNumber' - Try to guess the number that the computer has picked.";
    while(moduleRun){
        if(!gameRun){cout<<"\nChoose a new game\n";}
        gameRun = true;
        cout<<"\ngames>";
        cin>>cmd;
        if(cmd == "guessthenumber"){ guessthenumber(); }
        else if(cmd == "solve"){ solve(); }
        else if(cmd=="exit" || cmd =="quit"){ moduleRun = false; }
        else{cout<<"!Game not Available";}
    }
}
//End of Games Module

int main(){
    bool ProgramRun = true;
    h("The Math Thingy v0.01 by Nick K.",'=');
    cout<<"\n  Type 'calc' to initialize calculator \n  & 'cmdlist' for a list of commands\n";
    while(ProgramRun){
        if(!moduleRun){cout<<"Enter new command";}
        moduleRun = true;
        cout << "\n>>";
        cin >> cmd;
        if( cmd == "cmdlist" || cmd=="commands" ){
            cout << "\n\tcalc - Starts Arithmetic Calculator\n\tconv - Convert values to different units\n\tfunc - Scientific functions including sin, cos & tan\n\tquad - Finds the roots of a Quadratic Equation of the form ax^2 + bx + c = 0\n\tgames - Activates the games module\n\n";
        }
        else if( cmd == "calc" || cmd == "calculator" ){ calculator(); }
        else if( cmd == "func" ){functions();}
        else if( cmd == "conversions" || cmd == "conv" ){ converter(); }
        else if(cmd == "quad"){ quad(); }
        else if( cmd == "games" ){ games(); }
        else if( cmd == "exit" || cmd == "quit" || cmd == "0x0"){ ProgramRun = false; }
        else{ cout<<"Invalid command\n"; }
    }
}
```

---

**Things I would like addressed**:

- Ways to optimize and clean the code
- Mistake and errors in my programming practices
- Anything else which needs to corrected
- The [converter function](https://gist.github.com/NickKartha/6387434#file-maththingy-cpp-L180) is what significantly takes the most space in my program. How can I successfully decrease the amount of code for this function? I realize that I should, in some way, implement arrays fo this purpose but with my current knowledge of arrays in this language, I am not in a position to do so. I am in the process of learning more about them and in the meantime, I would appreciate the proposal of any method of optimally condensing the required code.
   <sub>(Note: I am willing conduct research into any topic on my own . All I ask for is to be pointed in the right direction)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try not to get into the habit of using [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- The "decorations" don't seem that useful and only clutters the code, so I'd remove them.  Don't worry about making the output look super nice (especially in a console environment).  Just focus on keeping the computational implementation nice.  You can, however, keep this simple by utilizing some functionality from the [`<iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) library.
- Do not use global variables:

  ```
  string cmd;
  bool moduleRun = true;
  ```

  Your code is already quite lengthy, and having these global will make maintenance painful if they end up being used unknowingly.  They should be used *locally* and passed to functions as needed.
- It appears that you're getting the square root here:

  ```
  long double l = floor(pow(n, 0.5));
  ```

  Why not just use `std::sqrt()`?

  ```
  long double l = std::floor(std::sqrt(n));
  ```

  I'd also recommend renaming `l` to something actually accurate.  Single-character variables, except as loop counters, add no context to its use, decreasing readability and maintainability (what if you completely forgot what it's for?).
- This is hard to read:

  ```
  (i==0)?cout<<"st":(i==1)?cout<<"nd":(i==2)?cout<<"rd":cout<<"th";
  ```

  If you cannot shorten it, at least rearrange it in a (slightly) more readable manner:

  ```
  (i == 0)
  ? cout << "st"
  : (i == 1)
  ? cout << "nd"
  : (i == 2)
  ? cout << "rd"
  : cout << "th";
  ```

  But this complexity can suggest that using ternary is *not* preferred.  Whether or not you can make this simpler, it may be beneficial to put this into its own function.  This is *not* `prod()`'s primary purpose, so having a separate function will make that purpose clearer.  It will also help maintain the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle.

Answer (score 7):

The command pattern is your friend.
You can then use a std::map to convert a user input string to a command during execution.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<double(double)>>    commands;

    commands["sin"] = [](double d) {return std::sin(d);};
    commands["cos"] = [](double d) {return std::cos(d);};
    //... etc.

    std::string command = argv[1];
    double      value   = std::atof(argv[2]);
    std::cout << commands[command](value) << "\n";
}
```

Your conversions can be done by a matrix:

```
   Unit
              m   c   <none>   d     h     k
   mili       0   1     2      3     4     5
   cente     -1   0     1      2     3     4
   <none>    -2  -1     0      1     2     3
   deca      -3  -2    -1      0     1     2
   hecto     -4  -3    -2     -1     0     1
   kilo      -5  -4    -3     -2    -1     0
```

So the table above defines the power conversion from one unit to another.

```
   int conversion[6][6] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5}, {-1,0,1,2,3,4}, .... };
   std::map<std::string, int>  data = {{ "m", 0 }, {"c", 1}, {"", 2}, {"d", 3}, {"h", 4}, {"k", 5}};

   std::string srcType  = "d";  // src deca
   std::string dstType  = "k";  // kilo
   int   src = data[srcType];
   int   dst = data[dstType];
   int result = n * pow(10, conversion[src][dst]);
```